# Find a word in array and store into new array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, find

I have an array like

```
Array
(
   [0] => Canon ProII PE-1000GC (MBL), Metallic Blue Electric Guitar
   [1] => Captain Tsubasa DVD Box
   [2] => Canon EOS Kiss X4 (550D / Rebel T2i) + Double Zoom Lens Kit
   [3] => Fresh Chiba Roasted Seaweed
)
```

if i am try to find `canon` my expected result is given below

```
Array
(
   [0] => Canon ProII PE-1000GC (MBL), Metallic Blue Electric Guitar      
   [1] => Canon EOS Kiss X4 (550D / Rebel T2i) + Double Zoom Lens Kit      
)
```

How can i find and store this array into anther variable. please guide me.

Comment: Why give Down vote for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the values and use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) to search the value for the word `Canon`.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
   if (strpos($value, 'Canon') !== false) { //if string contains 'Canon'
    $newArray[] = $value; //store it into a new array
   }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Canon ProII PE-1000GC (MBL), Metallic Blue Electric Guitar
    [1] => Canon EOS Kiss X4 (550D / Rebel T2i) + Double Zoom Lens Kit
)
```

[**Working demo!**](http://codepad.org/MPIxtrDs)

Comment: i have one doubt. some one person down vote for this question. if i made any mistake please tell me i will rectify my self.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of research effort. It's usually helpful to include your attempts in the question. See [**this**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) guide by Jon Skeet: